# По клику на изображение скачать из облака mp3

Tags: java, android

не получается реализовать такую задумку:
имеется коллекция (музыка,изображения)

```
 Map<String, Integer> imageCountru = new HashMap<>();
```

отдельно коллекция для изображений:

```
Map<String, Integer> mImageViews = new HashMap<>();
```

код главного класса и отрисовка списка:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRandom = new Random();

    mCircleRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.circle_recycler_view);


    mAdapter = new CircleAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 12);

    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch (position % 7) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    return 3;
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                    return 4;
            }
            return 3;
        }
    });

    mCircleRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    mCircleRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ima = new ImageCountru();
```

ima.ininitialize();
        ima.add();

```
    some();

}
```

Примеры ссылок:

```
 String england = "http://zaycev-tut.ru/load/0-0-0-1450-20";
String england1 = "http://zaycev-tut.ru/load/0-0-0-1450-202";
String england2 = "http://zaycev-tut.ru/load/0-0-0-1450-220";
String england3 = "http://zaycev-tut.ru/load/0-0-0-1450-2230";
String england4 = "http://zaycev-tut.ru/load/0-0-0-1450-2440";
String england5 = "http://zaycev-tut.ru/load/0-0-0-1450-244440";
String england6 = "http://zaycev-tut.ru/load/0-0-0-1450-2ddd0";
String england7 = "http://zaycev-tut.ru/load/0-0-0-1450-2dw0";
```

Код добавления в коллекцию:

```
 public void ininitialize() {

    mImageViews.put(england, R.drawable.belarus);
    mImageViews.put(england, R.drawable.england);

    mImageViews.put(england, R.drawable.finland);
    mImageViews.put(england1, R.drawable.france);
    mImageViews.put(england2, R.drawable.russia);
    mImageViews.put(england3, R.drawable.japan);
    mImageViews.put(england4, R.drawable.litva);
    mImageViews.put(england5, R.drawable.russia);
    mImageViews.put(england6, R.drawable.ukraine);
    mImageViews.put(england7, R.drawable.ukraine);


}

public void add() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> img : mImageViews.entrySet()) {

        imageCountru.put((img.getKey()), img.getValue());
    }

}
```

Тут код на получение из коллекции  imageCountru через экземпляр класса значений коллекции.

```
  void some() {

    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = ima.imageCountru.entrySet().iterator();
            it.hasNext(); ) {
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = it.next();

            int n = entry.getValue();

        mAdapter.addItem(n);
    }

}
```

В сети нашел код, который должен скачивать файл из заданного ему url и сохранять файл под именем в папку:

```
void clik(){
    try {

        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = ima.imageCountru.entrySet().iterator();
                it.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry<String, Integer> entrys = it.next();

            link = entrys.getKey();
        }
        //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
        //this is the file to be downloaded
        URL url = new URL(link);

        //create the new connection
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //set up some things on the connection
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        //and connect!
        urlConnection.connect();

        //set the path where we want to save the file
        //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
        //sd card.
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
        //which we want to save the file as.
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"somefile.ext");

        //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //this is the total size of the file
        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        //variable to store total downloaded bytes
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

        //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
            //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
           // updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

        }
        //close the output stream when done
        fileOutput.close();

        //catch some possible errors...
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:**
как правильно составить код для того,что бы по нажатию на какой-то элемент imageview из коллекции скачивался файл и сохранялся в папку с музыкой?

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
не хватает знаний на реализацию,т.е кликнул на какое-то изображение из коллекции ,после чего началась загрузка файла (звука)соответсвующего ключа,данный файл должен быть загружен на карту или память под свои именем

Comment: Вы не ответили на мой вопрос, а лишь повторили то, что написали в вопросе.

Comment: Вы можете назначить `listner` в методе `onBindViewHolder(...)` адаптера.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
не получаетя реализовать,не хватает знаний

Comment: @ s8am
а потом что?

Comment: @upward, вы или задайте конкретный вопрос или... Надейтесь что кому то будет не лень написать за вас код. Во втором случае гораздо эффективнее будет обратиться на фриланс-биржу

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
как изменить код на загрузку фала так,что бы я получал в url нажатый элемент и скачивал его

Comment: @upward, В `Listner` выполняете действия для загрузки файла.

Comment: для начала, вы не устанавливаете нигде onClick.

Comment: @ s8am
а что передавать,А точнее как правильно передать выбранынй элемент сюда:
URL url = new URL(link);